# Magento admin panel WYSIWYG editor

Tags: php, apache, magento

Magento admin panel does not show images in WYSIWYG editor in cms pages, when we click the url in a new tab, it shows in a junked format. Able to add the images. But the frontend displayed the images well.

����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ��C       $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C   2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222��"d"��  ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������     ���w!1AQaq"2�B����  #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?��F;@T�/����݂@'�����ndy�)*�����㿭k^[���P�.ON�4Z�<�a9+FџN3�lⰔd���p���gk �TD ��#v~�r�Py�o���X��`:�zx�[���T��F˝�*1�Z̶��r�d�V �?0� ���n1�8��I6�]�VR�+�5wIӍ��$�L�6I�}{Ѭ���ۈ"���*�RA#$t9=�W�ȱ�������;���x��(�"��������? �m�̌I�ns��~T���7<�@w>w~��9]��gf�h��P�T�&������=8��M��ʕS���X�pG���KWʻS��B� .q�#��zS��l��sd�NI�d՚(��`*�p1��o���QG,{R(��j�O��QL�(��(��(��(���

Comment: Are you using gzip or some other form of compression on your server?

Comment: No, We didn't find any compression for images